# Why doesn't this vlookup formula using the indirect function work?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-indirect

I am using `VLOOKUP` but rather than hardcode a reference to the file's location I want to use the `INDIRECT` function to reference the file's location.  However, my attempt at it doesn't work.  What's wrong with this?

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, INDIRECT(A1)$A$2:$B$1000,2,FALSE)
```

Where cell A1 contains:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\[ABC.xlsm]Sheet1
```

I get the error: The formula you typed contains an error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you need single quotes `'` in there...

Also, it looks like this is just broken as-is. You need something removed. There is no comma in `INDIRECT(A1)$A$2:$B$1000`. Perhaps you meant to reference that range within the sheet?

Comment: Also the external sheet lookup format should be: `[WORKBOOK.xls (or .xlsx or whichever format you use)]SHEETNAME!RANGE` with single quotes in the event spaces are present, as they appear to be in yours, around the names. i.e. `'[Workbook Path\Workbook Name.xls]!Sheet Name'!RANGE`

Comment: Is it possible to reference the file where the data is located, and not the range?  The idea is that I want to be able to change the filename to anything I want (while the range searched for remains constant).

Comment: It is possible to do that reference, but you won't be able to complete your `VLookup()` without a range, I believe. If I'm wrong and it *is* possible, then I think you'd be referencing the whole thing (essentially a default range) which would be very slow... Also, I was wrong before... the correct format is `'Workbook Path\[Workbook Name.xls]!Sheet Name'!RANGE`

Comment: Hi Gaffi, thanks for your help.  It turns out houdini's line does exactly what I was looking for.  I never would have been able to figure this one out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a syntax like this

`=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!$A$2:$B$1000"),2,FALSE)`

....but note that INDIRECT won't work if the source workbook is closed

Comment: Thank you houdini. your magic worked.  I would never have been able to figure out that syntax, especially where the first apostrophe is in quotes, and the second apostrophe isn't in quotes.  Now everything's working!